# Install mod_wsgi for python 3.8 on Debian 9/10

Tags: python, debian, mod-wsgi

[enter link description here](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libpython3.8-dev/download)Installing mod_wsgi on Ubunty with an upgraded [python 3.8 is easy enough](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1086649/how-to-update-python-to-the-latest-version-on-ubuntu-18-04). But with Debian I got stuck in unexpected errors.

I successfully installed [python3.8 from source](https://idroot.us/install-python-3-8-debian-10/), but when in the virtual environment I wanted to pip install mod_wsgi, I got a lot of errors. I assume that these occur because python3.8-dev and maybe even python3.8-distutils are not installed, but when I try to apt install them I always get an error

> Unable to locate package python3.8-dev

or

> Unable to locate package python3.8-distutils

, respectively. I checked/modified the file  **/etc/apt/sources.list**, but nothing changed. I wonder why it is so easy to install these components in Ubuntu which also is an Debian based Linux distribution, isn't it. I also wonder why there is no google hit with that problem which should have affected many, so maybe this post will generate one, and will hopefully generate a definite answer if it is possible or impossible at all to save others a lot of research.

**Update**

By the help of Max' answer I could find a proper solution simply by adding the line

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian sid main
```

to the **/etc/apt/sources.list** file as recommended [on the linked page](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libpython3.8-dev/download). Though my Debian distribution is *stretch* it seems to work with *sid* as well which has the more abundant libraries.

After adding that line I had to execute

```
apt update
apt install python3.8-dev
apt --fix-broken install
```

of course. When finished **mod_wsgi** could be pip installed.

Answer (score 2):

First of all :

```
Unable to locate package python3.8-dev
```

is not a error.

of course the package is there : i was quickly able to find it in sid. (https://packages.debian.org/sid/libpython3.8-dev)

there are all the architectures.
the direct link is here :

```
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3.8/libpython3.8-dev_3.8.5-2_amd64.deb
wget http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python3-stdlib-extensions/python3-distutils_3.8.5-1_all.deb

dpkg -i libpython3.8-dev_3.8.5-2_amd64.deb python3-distutils_3.8.5-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thank you it this might help everybody to manually install Debian packages though it is cumbersome as dependencies are not installed automatically. I found a better solution on the linked page by switching to 'sid'.